# following webscraping in python tutorial they use urllib im using requests help translating instructions

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I think I have translated the instructions so far well enough but now im lost. I don't have a lot of programming knowledge or skill.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



def make_soup(url):
    thepage = requests.get(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage.text, "html.parser")
    return soupdata


i = 1
soup = make_soup("https://uwaterloo.ca")

for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    temp = img.get('src')
    if temp[:1]=="/":
        image = "https://uwaterloo.ca" + temp
    else:
        image = temp

    nametemp = img.get('alt')
    if len(nametemp) == 0:
        filename = str(i)
        i = i + 1
    else:
        filename = nametemp
```

this is where I get lost on what to do

```
imagefile = open(filename + ".jpeg", 'wb')
imagefile.write(urllib.request.urlopen(image).read()
imagefile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the urllib logic with *requests.get* and write the content to file:

```
with open(filename + ".jpeg", 'wb') as f:         
    f.write(requests.get(image).content)
```

`f.write(requests.get(image).content)` is equivalent to what the urllib code is doing. Using the context manager *with* means your file will be automatically closed.

We can also improve the code a little using a css selector and str.format:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = requests.get(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage.text, "html.parser")
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup("https://uwaterloo.ca")
i = 1
for img in soup.select('img[src]'):
    temp = img["src"]
    alt = img["alt"]
    if not alt:
        alt = i
        i += 1
    if temp.startswith("/"):
        temp = urljoin("https://uwaterloo.ca", temp)
    with open("{}{}.jpeg".format(alt, i), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(requests.get(temp).content)
```